# Trouble with binding to a data grid nested inside of a tab control that has its data context pragmatically set

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am relatively new to WPF and MVVM, I dont understand why my bindings won't work. If you have any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

**View**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestEval.View.BuilderView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="400" Width="300"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestEval.ViewModel">
<Grid>
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="319" Margin="0,81,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedEvaluation.Groups}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Group" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedEvaluation.Groups.Questions}" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}">
                                    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <Label Content="{Binding Content}"></Label>
                                                <Label Content="*" IsEnabled="{Binding IsRequired}" ></Label>
                                                <Label Content="Answer Type:"></Label>

                                            </StackPanel>

                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                                </DataGrid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
    <Button Content="[+] Group" Command="{Binding AddGroupCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="215,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
```

**View Models**

This is the view model that holds the tabs and sets the data context for them

```
    namespace TestEval.ViewModel
    {
        class BuilderViewModel: ViewModelBase
        {
        private ObservableCollection<TabItem> tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();

        public ObservableCollection<TabItem> Tabs
        {
            get { return tabs; }
            set
            {
                tabs = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Tabs");
            }
        }

        private int selectedIndex;

        public int SelectedIndex
        {
            get { return selectedIndex; }
            set
            {
                selectedIndex = value;
                SelectedEvaluation = Tabs[selectedIndex].DataContext as EvaluationViewModel;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
            }
        }

        private EvaluationViewModel selectedEvaluation;

        public EvaluationViewModel SelectedEvaluation
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedEvaluation;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedEvaluation = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEvaluation");
            }
        }

        private object selected;

        public object Selected
        {
            get { return selected; }
            set
            {
                if (value == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                selected = value;
                if (selected is Group)
                {
                    selected = selected as Group;
                }
                else
                {
                    selected = selected as Question;
                }
            }
        }

        private RelayCommand addGroupCommand;

        public ICommand AddGroupCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (addGroupCommand == null)
                {
                    addGroupCommand = new RelayCommand(p => this.AddGroup(), p => this.CanAddGroup);
                }
                return addGroupCommand;
            }
        }

        public BuilderViewModel()
        {
            Tabs.Add(new TabItem{ Header = "Company Evaluation", DataContext = new EvaluationViewModel("Company") });
            Tabs.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Customer Evaluation", DataContext = new EvaluationViewModel("Customer") });
        SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        public bool CanAddGroup
        {
            get
            {
                 return SelectedEvaluation != null;
            }

        }

        void AddGroup()
        {
            SelectedEvaluation.Groups.Add(new Group(){Name = "GroupTest"});
        }
    }
}
```

Evaluation ViewModel

```
namespace TestEval.ViewModel
{
    public class EvaluationViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Group> groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>();

        public ObservableCollection<Group> Groups
        {
            get { return groups; }
            set
            {
                groups = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Groups");
            }
        }

        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public EvaluationViewModel(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
   }
}
```

**Models**

Group Model

```
namespace TestEval.Model
{
    public class Group : ObservableObject
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Question> questions = new ObservableCollection<Question>();

        public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions
        {
            get { return questions; }
            set
            {
                questions = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Questions");
            }
        }

        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }  
    }

}
```

Question Model

```
public class Question : ObservableObject
{
    private Guid id;
    private string content;
    private string answerType;
    private string answers;
    private bool isRequired;
    private string group;
    private bool showAnswers = false;

    public Guid Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public string Content
    {
        get { return content; }
        set
        {
            content = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Content");
        }
    }

    public string AnswerType
    {
        get { return answerType; }
        set
        {
            answerType = value;
            if (answerType == "SingleChoice" || answerType == "MultipleChoice")
            {
                ShowAnswers = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ShowAnswers = false;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("AnswerType");
        }
    }

    public string Answers
    {
        get { return answers; }
        set
        {
            answers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Answers");
        }
    }

    public string Group
    {
        get { return group; }
        set
        {
            group = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Group");
        }

    }

    public bool IsRequired
    {
        get { return isRequired; }
        set
        {
            isRequired = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsRequired");
        }
    }

    public bool ShowAnswers
    {
        get { return showAnswers; }
        set
        {
            showAnswers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ShowAnswers");
        }
    }

    public Question()
    {

    }

    public Question(string content, string answerType, string answers, bool isRequired)
    {
        this.Id = new Guid();
        this.Content = content;
        this.AnswerType = answerType;
        this.Answers = answers;
        this.IsRequired = isRequired;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you change the `DataContext` in your `View.cs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually not too far off, I think you're just missing a few key points about how data binding works in MVVM.

The most serious problem is that you've got an array of TabItem in your view model. Doing this is not proper MVVM, in fact it should never be done at all. TabItem is a control element and therefore belongs in the view only, you should be creating a view model for your tabs, adding a collection of those to your parent view model instead and then binding to that in your TabControl. To illustrate why this is wrong, try this: place your grid in a StackPanel with Orientation set to Vertical and then try adding a duplicate TabControl bound to the same collection of TabItem. Tabs will start disappearing from one control as you click around because TabItem can only have one parent and you're now trying to bind it to two.

To fix this problem add a header field to your EvaluationViewModel and adjust your constructor to accept the header as well:

```
    private string _Header;
    public string Header
    {
        get { return this._Header; }
        set { this._Header = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Header); }
    }
```

Now change your tabs property to be a `ObservableCollection<EvaluationViewModel>`, you should now be setting it up like this:

```
Tabs.Add(new EvaluationViewModel("Company Evaluation", "Company"));
Tabs.Add(new EvaluationViewModel("Customer Evaluation", "Customer"));
SelectedEvaluation = Tabs.First(); // you'll see why I'm doing this in a moment
```

Back in your tab control your TabsItems will be created automatically and their DataContext will each be set to the corresponding EvaluationViewModel, so set DisplayMemberPath to indicate which field is the header, get rid of the SelectedIndex binding and the corresponding SelectedIndex property in your view model (you don't need it) and bind SelectedItem directly to your SelectedEvaluation property. Your TabControl XAML should now look like this:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" DisplayMemberPath="Header" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEvaluation}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ... etc...
```

Now when your `TabControl.ContentTemplate` is instantiated its DataContext is set to be the same as the DataContext for its corresponding Tab. There are two places in that template where you're explicitly binding to SelectedEvaluation i.e. `SelectedEvaluation.Groups` and `SelectedEvaluation.Groups.Questions`. Change those to `Groups` and `Groups.Questions`.

Finally, you're not initializing your Groups collection, but I'm sure you would have eventually figured that one out yourself:

```
private ObservableCollection<Group> _Groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>();
```

This will achieve what you're trying to do. Post back here if you need clarification on anything.

Comment: This was perfect! Thank you!